# Most Efficient Mode Function In Java

Tags: java, mode

I have a huge int array which I need to find the Mode of,

Ive seen a few methods that use 2 `for` loops (one nested) which seems unnecessary.

The only way I can think to find the mode with only one loop involves using `Map`s:

```
int[] elements = new int[]{....numbers...};
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new .....Map Type....;
for(int number : elements){
    if(map.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(number))){
        map.put(Integer.valueOf(number),map.get(Integer.valueOf(number))+1);
    }else{
        map.put(Integer.valueOf(number),1);
    }
}
```

Im not sure what kind of speed benefits using maps would actually give.
Is there a better method?

Comment: It looks like you are adding extra overhead, not quite sure if this will improve it.

Comment: "speed benefits using colllections" - What do you mean by collections here? In the code, `collection` just seems to be a `Map`.

Comment: also, you dont have to make Integer.valueOf, there's a thing called Autoboxing.

Comment: "Collection" does not have containsKey(), put()... It looks like a Map. Also you can skip the containsKey() step, because get() will return null if the element is not in the map.

Comment: @HariShankar I have edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: You cannot find the mode in less than O(N), because you'll have to count all the numbers in order to see which is encountered most frequently. The benefit of using a Map (HashMap) is that you have constant time (O(1)) access to each element of the map, just like accessing an array element by its index (but slower), but unlike arrays you will need memory only for the distinct key-value pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a hash map, the runtime complexity of your algorithm should be O(n): You visit each of the n elements once, and HashMap lookup and write is usually assumed to be O(1). So in total you get O(n * 1) which is O(n). If you use a tree map, you get O(n log n).

Compared to two nested loops (which sounds like O(n²)), the speed improvement is going from quadratic to linear, which is quite good: For 1000 elements, you perform 1000 "steps" instead of 1,000,000.

P.S. Getting better than linear is probably hard here -- can't imagine a way of calculating this without visiting each element at least once.

Comment: There is no such way - O(n) is a lower bound for this problem

Comment: If during the calculation you checked if `currentMaxCount-secondBestMaxCount > elementsRemaining` To see if its even worth continuing through the array, would that make it O(<n)?

Answer (score 5):

As Stefan Haustein already wrote, the complexity using a map is much lower than using 2 for loops.

There is one further improvement or rather specialization that can be done if you know the range of numbers stored inside your array. For example if you count colors which are in the range of 0-255, you don't have to use a map and instead can use a simple array.

```
int[] elements = new int[]{....numbers...};
int[] histogram = new int[256]; // 255 = highest possible value in elements
for(int number : elements){
  ++histogram[number];    
}
```

Using a map is a more generalized way. You can think of a map as an array with a more complex indexing function. So in a normal array the number is at `array pointer + index` while in a map this is calculated using a liner hash function.

Answer (score 0):

No algorithm can be faster than O(n) (have a look at the wikipedia page for [big-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). At least, not consistently (across all possible inputs). This does not mean that it cannot go any faster -- just that, beyond a certain problem size, whatever is faster can't keep on increasing the speed difference by more than a (probably small) linear factor.

This is because, whatever the order in which you examine the elements, given an array that is "almost balanced" as to the winner, the last element you examine can turn out to be the tiebreaker. Give me any algorithm that doesn't look at all elements, and I can write a input array that will make it return incorrect results. Therefore, you have to examine all of them at least once: O(n) complexity.

Hashmaps have general insert and lookup complexities of O(1) -- that is, on average, regardless of the size of the data, they take up a constant time to do their thing. Note that this constant time is several times larger than, say, array update/lookups (see **TwoThe**'s answer). Therefore, except for constants (which will vary depending on hashmap implementation, machine, VM, and so on), you can't get much faster than the code you posted. If you really need that 10% extra performance, then build a benchmark on hardware/software/input data as near as possible to your intended deployment and optimize *that*.